# Remove the time bit of datepicker using CSS in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, datepicker

I have a wordpress site that uses a date/time picker for a booking site. I need to hide the time part that shows up when you pick a date ==> January 13, 2017 23:18

I want to do this using CSS. Someone please help. The code is

```
<input type="text" class="departure-date" id="departure-date">
                        <input type="hidden" name="dep" id="dep" value="<?php echo (isset($departure_date) ? esc_attr($departure_date) : ''); ?>" />
                        <?php if (isset($departure_date)) { ?>
                            <script>
                            window.datepickerDepartureDateValue = '<?php echo esc_js(date(TRANSFERS_PHP_DATE_FORMAT, strtotime($departure_date))); ?>';
                            </script>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how or why you plan on modifying input text with CSS, but good luck. Joking aside, CSS is a *styling* language - it is most certainly not the solution to your problem.

Comment: Have you tried this? $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                 format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
           });?

Comment: Hi  @Valius79 , please where do I insert the code?

Comment: @Santi, Please can you recommend a solution? I'll greatly appreciate that. Thanks.